# Process finished with exit code 0 for Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm new to Pycharm but as a beginner, I know I get "Process finished with exit code 0" which means that My code doesn't have any error, but the code is running only 2 seconds. Could you guys help me out, please? Much appreciate it!

D:\TelegramBots\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/TelegramBots/main.py

Bot started...

Process finished with exit code 0

[Image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq1HT.png)

```
import Constants as Keys
from telegram.ext import *
import Responses as R

print("Bot started...")


def start_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Type something to get started!')


def help_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('If you need help you should ask Google!')


def handle_command(update, context):
    text = str(update.message.text).lower()
    response = R.sample_responses(text)

    update.message.reply_text(response)


def error(update, context):
    print(f"Update {update} caused error {context.error}")


def main():
    updater = Updater(Keys.API_KEY, use_context=True)
    dp = Updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_command))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler(Filters.text, start_command))

    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    updater.start_polling(10)
    updater.idle()

    main()
```

Comment: What's wrong with it only running in two seconds?

Comment: I think you need to indent out `main()` from the main function.

Comment: @KaushalSharma can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: @blackdevil you are `main()` inside `main()`, just remove the space in front of `main()`  in the last line and it should be running.

Comment: Thanks @KaushalSharma it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is only defining functions so it runs and then doesn’t perform any of them.

Where you call `main()` (line 41) do not indent and your program will run as expected.

Comment: you can check that I have called main() to the bot API, but still the same 

`def main():     updater = Updater(Keys.API_KEY, use_context=True) 

dp = Updater.dispatcher`

Answer (score 0):

I removed the space in front of main() in the last line, now it's working